# optimization method to solve a problem

Tags: operations-research

A small petroleum company owns two refineries. Refinery 1 costs \$20,000 per day to
operate, and it can produce 400 barrels of high-grade oil, 300 barrels of medium-grade oil,
and 200 barrels of low-grade oil each day. Refinery 2 is newer and more modern. It costs \$25,000 per day to operate, and it can produce 300 barrels of high-grade oil, 400 barrels of
medium-grade oil, and 500 barrels of low-grade oil each day.
The company has orders totaling 25,000 barrels of high-grade oil, 27,000 barrels of
medium-grade oil, and 30,000 barrels of low-grade oil. How many days should it run each
refinery to minimize its costs and still refine enough oil to meet its orders?

**Using the optimization method**, how can we solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The following diagram depicts what is happening. Yet, please, calculate the exact solution yourself.

[image: diagram]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: What software did you use to draw the pretty figure?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm glad you liked it, thank you. I'm using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and I recommend it very very much.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the number of days refinery $1$ is run and $y$ the number of days  refinery $2$ is run.

Your function to optimize is :
$$f(x,y) = 20000x + 25000y$$
Your constraints are :
$$
400x + 300y \geq 25000 \\
300x + 400y \geq 27000 \\
200x + 500y \geq 30000
$$
(Note we cannot use strict equality because it leads to a non-solution system).

Since $f$ is increasing in both argument we need to consider the boundary on the region defined by the constraint and analyze $f$ on this boundary to find its minimum.

Comment: Don't bother doing her homework. She will delete the question soon.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo You can't self-delete a question that has an answer with upvotes.

Comment: @dtldarek What if it has $n$ upvotes and $n$ downvotes?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't know, you can ask on meta ;-)